# How to measure memory usage with C# (as we can do in Java)?

Tags: c#, java, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to measure, in a C# programm, the memory usage.

I'd like to know the C# equivalent of this Java function :

```
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted()
```

that represent the total memory **allocated** for the heap. I need this to know the total size of memory allocated for my C# programm.

Then in Java I can get the used memory with :

```
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()
```

Currently I use this in C# to get used memory :

```
Process_Memory = MyProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

But I'm not totally sure that it's the equivalent.

So in resume how can I get the total allocated space for my C# application and the current use at a time *t*?

***EDIT :***

From the answers and further research I've determine this :

***Current memory in use***

```
System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
```

> Give the number of bytes currently allocated in managed memory. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

This method return a low value and I'm pretty sure it's not really a representation of all memory in use as I can get with `getUsed()` in *Java*. In java for the same application used memory start at 5MB and go to 125MB max. With C# I get from 1 to 5 MB with above method.

It seems that :

```
MyProcess.PrivateMemorySize64; // return ~=25MB
```

or

```
MyProcess.WorkingSet64;  //return ~=20MB
```

Give a more accurate value of all the memory in use. But I don't know wich one I should use...

> 

For the ***global allocated memory*** [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2007/10/13/memory-working-set-explored.aspx) suggests to use :

```
Process_MemoryEnd1 = MyProcess.VirtualMemorySize64;
```

It return ***always the same value*** along the programm, about 169MB that seems fair compared to Java : from 64MB to 170MB max

I'm still looking for an accurate answer all I found is very vague and I'm not very familiar with Windows memory management, I'm not really sure to undertand the docs I found :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `GC` static class provides all this type of information.

Your probably after `GC.GetTotalMemory()`.

EDIT:

I beleive that attempts to workout your memory footprint based on currently rooted objects.
IF you want the total size allocated for the process (i.e. including the free buffer) use the `Process` class. e.g.:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
```

Comment: Yes I know this but it give the actual size of objects in the managed heap, it's a low value. I don't think this is representative of all the allocated memory.

Comment: Then I believe you just need to use all those properties of the `Process` class if you want raw allocated memory (i.e. not taking into account any of the managed GC functionality). `PagedMemorySize64`, `PrivateMemorySize64`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, so I think if I want just the processus total allocated memory `PrivateMemorySize64` can be enough. I don't get what is paged memory...

Comment: Well it's an edge case. If the physical RAM is full, the OS will use a chunk of your HDD as 'memory', called 'virtual memory'. So if your being really pedantic and want the total, you really should add them all up, just in case. I am not sure if `WorkingSet64` takes virtual memory into account. MSDN says "WorkingSet64: Gets the amount of physical memory allocated for the associated process."

Comment: Ok so I want the total allocated memory I add `NonpagedSystemMemorySize64` + `PagedMemorySize64` + `PagedSystemMemorySize64` + `PrivateMemorySize64` + `WorkingSet64` ?

Comment: Nope. `WorkingSet` is definetly the sum of atleast some of those. And it sounds like `PagedMemorySize == VirtualMemorySize`. I normally just use `WorkingSet` by itself. These are good questions though, perhaps the topic for a new question?

Comment: I've edit the question rather than an other question, take a look ;) it's still quite unclear for me.

Answer (score 18):

Heres one way, using the GC:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        long kbAtExecution = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024;

        // do stuff that uses memory here 

        long kbAfter1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024;
        long kbAfter2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024;

        Console.WriteLine(kbAtExecution + " Started with this kb.");
        Console.WriteLine(kbAfter1 + " After the test.");
        Console.WriteLine(kbAfter1 - kbAtExecution + " Amt. Added.");
        Console.WriteLine(kbAfter2 + " Amt. After Collection");
        Console.WriteLine(kbAfter2 - kbAfter1 + " Amt. Collected by GC.");         
    }
```

Or alternatively using System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter to get working set info:

```
PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";

performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set";

performanceCounter.InstanceName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

Console.WriteLine(((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue()/1024).ToString("N0"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, as the doc says, `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)` return the number of bytes currently allocated in managed memory. I think it may be the equivalent of getUse() in java. But how I get the entire space allocated? Does ` System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` represent that value?

Comment: For the second solution it raised a `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @alain.janinm, Not sure why. Works on my system. Whats the error or inner exception say?

Comment: Heu the problem is that VS give error in French so I will try to translate  : Impossible to load the data of counter name, because an index is not valid '' as been read from register.

Comment: Using your GC-based approach I was getting very inconsistent numbers (variations on the order of 16x) for the same block of code. By adding `GC.Collect();` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` before it I was able to get *much* more consistent measurements.