# How to determine how much memory consumed by Add-on or BHO on IE in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management, bho

I have created a Add-on (BHO) in IE and now running into performance issue. I am not able to check how much memory my Add-on is consuming.

Actually it is not sure that Add-on is culprit or something else is there in browser

Comment: Writing a  BHO in .net is asking for problems, as for example what if the user had a different BHO loaded that needs a conflicting version of .net?

Answer (score 0):

Attach to Internet Explorer process and debug normally with Visual Studio, then you can execute methods from the Watch or the Immediate window using the methods that you can find here:

[How to get memory available or used in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750574/how-to-get-memory-available-or-used-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I did that earlier but seems like confusing to me, as i think i am not getting correct value of actual memory usage!! I was following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404946/how-to-measure-memory-usage-with-c-sharp-as-we-can-do-in-java

Comment: It should work. Why do you think you are not getting the correct value?

Comment: most of counters are providing information of Total memory allocated but not providing actual memory used by my process. Also memory is different than showing in task manager

Comment: To get the current memory usage you should use Process.WorkingSet property