# Memory taken by await objects

Tags: c#, async-await

What is the memory footprint of following code something like number of objects on heap.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            await MyMethod();
        }
```

Comment: You can check that yourself in Visual Studio. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404946/how-to-measure-memory-usage-with-c-sharp-as-we-can-do-in-java/9404984).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably a duplicate.

But the following calls to the `VirtualMemorySize64` method will get you the current size of the memory in bytes. If you wrap the operation you want to monitor and grab a snapshot before and after you can work out the total increase here.

Docs link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.virtualmemorysize64?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

long start = Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    await MyMethod();
}

long end = Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64;

// You can then get the total difference in bytes
long diff = end - start;
```